# HP BIOS update failed

Tags: usb, bios, updates, flash

My laptop model - HP Pavilion 15-p004nx Notebook.

I tried to flash bios using https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00042629.

I used bios recovery flash drive and and every time bios update failed.

Here I paste the "HpBiosUpdate.log" file logs from "USB_DRIVE:\Hewlett-Packard\BIOSUpdate" folder.

```
2014-01-01 07:17:51  EFI HP BIOS Update 3.4.0.0 Started
2014-01-01 07:17:52  System ID: 2281
2014-01-01 07:17:52  HP BIOS Image Interface Protocol Version 2.0
2014-01-01 07:17:52  BattInit: Protocol 2010.
2014-01-01 07:17:52  0 UART device path node found.
2014-01-01 07:17:52  All Required Protocols Located
2014-01-01 07:17:52  System ID: 2281
2014-01-01 07:17:52  HpBiosUpdate.Mode = 4
2014-01-01 07:17:52  Current Directory = HEWLETT-PACKARD\BIOSUpdate\
2014-01-01 07:17:52  SMBIOS Init Success
2014-01-01 07:17:52  SystemFamily = 2
2014-01-01 07:17:52  PlatformLang reported as en-US.
2014-01-01 07:17:52  Language Selected is currently (eng).
2014-01-01 07:17:53  Starting BIOS Update Process
2014-01-01 07:17:53  Setting BIOS Update Token
2014-01-01 07:17:53  Getting BIOS Detail Information
2014-01-01 07:17:53  BIOS Returned BiosID '0227D'
2014-01-01 07:17:53  Loading BIOS Image
2014-01-01 07:17:53  File name constructed: Hewlett-Packard\BIOS\Current\0227D.bin
2014-01-01 07:17:53  Reading New BIOS Image Hewlett-Packard\BIOS\Current\0227D.bin
2014-01-01 07:17:53  Getting BIOS version from file image
2014-01-01 07:17:53  Bios Version = F.53
2014-01-01 07:17:53  Verifying AC or Battery Power Status
2014-01-01 07:17:53  Verifying Binary match
2014-01-01 07:17:53  Loading Signature File
2014-01-01 07:17:53  Failed Reading BIOS Signature File Hewlett-Packard\BIOS\Current\0227D.sig
2014-01-01 07:17:53  Failed Reading .sig file. (Not Found)
2014-01-01 07:17:58  Bios Verify Signature Success (Success)
2014-01-01 07:17:58  Loading Password File if required
2014-01-01 07:17:58  BIOS Password not required.
2014-01-01 07:17:58  Writing BIOS Image
2014-01-01 07:18:53  Verifying Written BIOS Image
2014-01-01 07:19:40  Verify of Block 1056 Failed
2014-01-01 07:19:40  Verify of Block 1057 Failed
2014-01-01 07:19:40  Verify of Block 1058 Failed
2014-01-01 07:19:40  Verify of Block 1059 Failed
2014-01-01 07:19:40  Verify of Block 1060 Failed
2014-01-01 07:19:40  Verify of Block 1061 Failed
2014-01-01 07:19:41  Verify of Block 1062 Failed
2014-01-01 07:19:41  Verify of Block 1063 Failed
2014-01-01 07:19:41  Verify of Block 1064 Failed
2014-01-01 07:19:41  Verify of Block 1065 Failed
2014-01-01 07:19:41  Verify of Block 1077 Failed
2014-01-01 07:19:42  Skipping Verification Block 1104 Address 0x0000000000450000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:19:42  Next BlockIndex 1105, BlockAddress = 0x0000000000451000
2014-01-01 07:19:57  Skipping Verification Block 1771 Address 0x00000000006EB000 Size 0x0000000000011000
2014-01-01 07:19:57  Next BlockIndex 1788, BlockAddress = 0x00000000006FC000
2014-01-01 07:19:57  Skipping Verification Block 1788 Address 0x00000000006FC000 Size 0x0000000000060000
2014-01-01 07:19:57  Next BlockIndex 1884, BlockAddress = 0x000000000075C000
2014-01-01 07:19:57  Skipping Verification Block 1884 Address 0x000000000075C000 Size 0x00000000000A4000
2014-01-01 07:19:57  Next BlockIndex 2048, BlockAddress = 0x0000000000800000
2014-01-01 07:19:57  Failed VerifyImage Call Status (Device Error)
2014-01-01 07:19:58  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1056 Address 0x0000000000420000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:19:58  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1057 Address 0x0000000000421000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:19:58  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1058 Address 0x0000000000422000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:19:58  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1059 Address 0x0000000000423000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:19:58  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1060 Address 0x0000000000424000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:19:58  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1061 Address 0x0000000000425000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:19:58  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1062 Address 0x0000000000426000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:19:58  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1063 Address 0x0000000000427000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:19:58  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1064 Address 0x0000000000428000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:19:58  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1065 Address 0x0000000000429000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:19:58  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1077 Address 0x0000000000435000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:20:45  Verify of Block 1056 Failed
2014-01-01 07:20:45  Verify of Block 1057 Failed
2014-01-01 07:20:45  Verify of Block 1058 Failed
2014-01-01 07:20:45  Verify of Block 1059 Failed
2014-01-01 07:20:45  Verify of Block 1060 Failed
2014-01-01 07:20:45  Verify of Block 1061 Failed
2014-01-01 07:20:46  Verify of Block 1062 Failed
2014-01-01 07:20:46  Verify of Block 1063 Failed
2014-01-01 07:20:46  Verify of Block 1064 Failed
2014-01-01 07:20:46  Verify of Block 1065 Failed
2014-01-01 07:20:46  Verify of Block 1077 Failed
2014-01-01 07:20:47  Skipping Verification Block 1104 Address 0x0000000000450000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:20:47  Next BlockIndex 1105, BlockAddress = 0x0000000000451000
2014-01-01 07:21:02  Skipping Verification Block 1771 Address 0x00000000006EB000 Size 0x0000000000011000
2014-01-01 07:21:02  Next BlockIndex 1788, BlockAddress = 0x00000000006FC000
2014-01-01 07:21:02  Skipping Verification Block 1788 Address 0x00000000006FC000 Size 0x0000000000060000
2014-01-01 07:21:02  Next BlockIndex 1884, BlockAddress = 0x000000000075C000
2014-01-01 07:21:02  Skipping Verification Block 1884 Address 0x000000000075C000 Size 0x00000000000A4000
2014-01-01 07:21:02  Next BlockIndex 2048, BlockAddress = 0x0000000000800000
2014-01-01 07:21:02  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1056 Address 0x0000000000420000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:21:03  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1057 Address 0x0000000000421000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:21:03  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1058 Address 0x0000000000422000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:21:03  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1059 Address 0x0000000000423000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:21:03  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1060 Address 0x0000000000424000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:21:03  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1061 Address 0x0000000000425000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:21:03  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1062 Address 0x0000000000426000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:21:03  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1063 Address 0x0000000000427000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:21:03  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1064 Address 0x0000000000428000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:21:03  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1065 Address 0x0000000000429000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:21:03  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1077 Address 0x0000000000435000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:21:50  Verify of Block 1056 Failed
2014-01-01 07:21:50  Verify of Block 1057 Failed
2014-01-01 07:21:50  Verify of Block 1058 Failed
2014-01-01 07:21:50  Verify of Block 1059 Failed
2014-01-01 07:21:50  Verify of Block 1060 Failed
2014-01-01 07:21:50  Verify of Block 1061 Failed
2014-01-01 07:21:51  Verify of Block 1062 Failed
2014-01-01 07:21:51  Verify of Block 1063 Failed
2014-01-01 07:21:51  Verify of Block 1064 Failed
2014-01-01 07:21:51  Verify of Block 1065 Failed
2014-01-01 07:21:51  Verify of Block 1077 Failed
2014-01-01 07:21:52  Skipping Verification Block 1104 Address 0x0000000000450000 Size 0x0000000000001000
2014-01-01 07:21:52  Next BlockIndex 1105, BlockAddress = 0x0000000000451000
2014-01-01 07:22:07  Skipping Verification Block 1771 Address 0x00000000006EB000 Size 0x0000000000011000
2014-01-01 07:22:07  Next BlockIndex 1788, BlockAddress = 0x00000000006FC000
2014-01-01 07:22:07  Skipping Verification Block 1788 Address 0x00000000006FC000 Size 0x0000000000060000
2014-01-01 07:22:07  Next BlockIndex 1884, BlockAddress = 0x000000000075C000
2014-01-01 07:22:07  Skipping Verification Block 1884 Address 0x000000000075C000 Size 0x00000000000A4000
2014-01-01 07:22:07  Next BlockIndex 2048, BlockAddress = 0x0000000000800000
2014-01-01 07:22:07  Failed RetryBlocks Call Status (Device Error)
2014-01-01 07:22:08  Setting Flash Completion Status
2014-01-01 07:22:08  BIOS Update Process Complete
```

> Verify of Block 1056 Failed
>
> Failed RetryBlocks Call Status (Device Error)

And other similar messages. What is the real problem here?

Comment: I would download the bios file again and try one more time.  The first file may be corrupted or incomplete.

Comment: In addition to `Christopher Hostage's` answer, I advise you not attempt to reboot your pc until the update finishes successfully. It may seem like redundant advice, but many laptop motherboards have been bricked and RMA'd from this. It's a shame most computers don't come with dual-BIOS capability these days.

Comment: As @ChristopherHostage suggested, I downloaded the bios file again [link](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp80001-80500/sp80106.exe), made recovery drive and flashed but failed again. And I rechecked the log file, same logs as last one.

Comment: @Dooley_labs after bios update fails, It auto reboots and as there is no OS, black screen and no Fn key works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information you've provided in the comments, your laptop is bricked sadly, unless your laptop has a BIOS recovery port or method, which most do not.

In your case, your computer **does not** have a method to recover the BIOS, as you stated in your answer's link to HP's official documentation.

Your only solution would most likely be to RMA the laptop with HP, unless you want to attempt to swap the motherboard yourself, which I do not recommend. There are other ways to re-flash a BIOS chip, including a method with a Raspberry PI, however I do not condone these methods.

Comment: so only BIOS chip is corrupted and If I gave my laptop to repair center they'll try to re-flash the BIOS chip or there may be other causes for corrupted BIOS chip?

Comment: In this case, I'd assume it's only a corrupt BIOS chip. I'm not aware of many other causes, unless the chip itself is damaged.